# Listening to (IP address, UDP port) from Delphi firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, udp, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have a pipe outputting some message via a UDP port (IP address, UDP port) which I want to listen to from delphi firemonkey application. The pipe just outputs messages and doesn't handle connections. Which INDY component should I use in my delphi firemonkey application so that I can listen to (IP address, UDP port) and recieve the messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TIdUDPServer`.  Add an entry to its `Bindings` collection for the local IP/Port that you want to listen on, and assign an `OnUDPRead` event handler to handle received packets as needed.